# willHideViewController not calld when application is in landscape mode

Tags: ios

I am creating an iPhone universal application and implemented the  willHideViewController method. This method is called on the iPad portrait mode but not called on the iPad landscape mode.
Can anyone give the solutions?

Comment: Add code to understand...

Answer (score 2):

`willHideViewController` has been deprecated since iOS8 ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontrollerdelegate/1623175-splitviewcontroller?language=objc))

You need to use `splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode:` method instead because there are no garantee that `willHideViewController` will continue to work properly (and you found a case where it's not !)

Comment: no its nor working i am implementing the following method this method successfully called on ipad portrait mode but not call on ipad landscape mode.
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{
   // I am implement custom left bar button in this method.
  
}

Comment: If you give your implementation of willHideViewController, we may be able to help you to translate your code, but unless you target iOS < 8 ; witch seems unlikely for a Universal app (splitviewcontroller are not universal before iOS 8, you really should not use willHideViewController. It need to be replaced by willChangeToDisplayMode

Answer (score 1):

`willHideViewController` is deprecated, maybe that’s the case you face that issue.

use `splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode:` beside of `willHideViewController`